# Prolog Subset Return Values To List

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to return the subsets of a certain list in another list to do some operations on them, my code for finding the subsets is as follows:

```
listSubset([] , []).
listSubset([Head|Tail] , [Head|Subset]) :- 
    listSubset(Tail, Subset).
listSubset([Head|Tail] , Subset) :-
    listSubset(Tail, Subset).
```

but this code only prints the subsets on the screen and whenever I try to use append to append each subset in another list, the code does not work as I expect it to.

one of the ways I tried to use append:

```
listSubset([] , [], AllSubSets).
listSubset([Head|Tail] , [Head|Subset], AllSubSets) :- 
    appendx([[Head|Subset]], AllSubSets, NewAllSubSets),
    listSubset(Tail, Subset, NewAllSubSets).
listSubset([Head|Tail] , Subset, AllSubSets) :-
    listSubset(Tail, Subset, AllSubSets).
    
appendx([],List,List).
appendx([H|T],List,[H|T2]) :- 
    appendx(T,List,T2).
```

Comment: Show how you are using `append/3`, as the problem seems to be at this point.

Comment: @slago I can't put the code so I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To collect all subsets of a set in a list, just ask:

```
?- findall(S, listSubset([a,b,c],S), L).
L = [[a, b, c], [a, b], [a, c], [a], [b, c], [b], [c], []].
```

Comment: that works as a question in the SWI-Prolog app, but can I use when writing the code to use this list in other operations?

Comment: Yes, you can use it! It works!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you append your subsets to the list. This should work fine

```
listSubset([] , [], AllSubSets).

listSubset([Head|Tail] , [Head|Subset], AllSubSets) :- 
    appendx([[Head|Subset]], AllSubSets, NewAllSubSets),
    listSubset(Tail, Subset, NewAllSubSets).

listSubset([Head|Tail] , Subset, AllSubSets) :-

appendx(Subset, AllSubSets, NewAllSubSets),

    listSubset(Tail, Subset, AllSubSets).
    
appendx([],List,List).
appendx([H|T],List,[H|T2]) :- 
    appendx(T,List,T2).
```